# PriorityQueue and ArrayList better together?

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to know the best possible way to sort a file.txt lines in a Java collection.

Using orderedSet removes duplication and I don't want that.

PriorityQueue does the job but I need my class to be Iterable and using PriorityQueue.Iterator does not give sorted results.

Now I am confused with using Arrays.sort or going with this approach:
using PriorityQueue when reading lines from text then copying the final Queue on an array to use its Iterator?

```
public class FileSorter implements Iterable<String> {
    // this sorted set contains the lines
    private PriorityQueue<String> lines0 =  new PriorityQueue<>() ;
    private ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public void readFiles (String[] filePaths) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buf = null;
        String line ;
        for (String path:filePaths) {
            //opening the file
            buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

            //iterating through the lines and adding them the collection
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.trim().length() > 0) {  //no blank lines
                    lines0.add(line);
                }
            }
        };

        //closing the buffer
        buf.close();

        while (!lines0.isEmpty()){
            lines.add(lines0.poll());
        }
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return lines.iterator();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: Oleg : TreeSet removes duplications !! maybe my post wasn't clear enough , i still want duplications

Comment: ok, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819550/efficiently-ordered-data-structure-that-supports-duplicate-keys

Comment: What is the problem in using ArrayList?

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee  : in the performance side , Using PriorityQueue while reading from text file then copy it to an arrayList using .poll() or reading the file to an ArrayList then using Collections.sort() wich one is better ?

Comment: Thanks Oleg: since my case is reading all file then sort , the link indicates it is better to use .sort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think implementing `Iterable` is not the best approach because you should prefer composition over inheritance, and it's 2017 after all; no one implements their own collection classes anymore. That said, how about the following?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        for (String line : new FileSorter(new File(Main.class.getResource("test.txt").toURI()).toPath())) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    static class FileSorter implements Iterable<String> {
        private final Path path;

        FileSorter(Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            try {
                return Files.lines(path)
                        .sorted()
                        .iterator();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given a file `test.txt` in the same dir as the class `Main`:

```
a
b
a
c
```

The above program prints:

```
a
a
b
c
```

`Iterable` has different semantic than `Stream` because the former can be reused, while the latter can only be used once (until a terminal operation). Thus, my implementation reads the file every time you call `iterator()`. I didn't attempt to optimize it because you didn't ask for it, and premature optimization is the root of all evil.